# InfoPath form sent as attachment but permission changed

Tags: infopath, email, attachments

I've published InfoPath form to SharePoint for users to fill in. Then, I sent this form as an attachment in an email because I need to provide step-by-step guidelines for them. Apparently, the form does not work out when it was sent as an attachment. It shows ' You do not have sufficient permission to perform this operation on this item'.

Has anyone got clue on this? Thanks!!